# extract values from array (php or jquery)

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, extract

I've got an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [username] => myusername
    [created_at] => 2013-01-01 15:30:27
    [public_id] => aaabbbccc112233
    [reputation] => 16
    [hourly_quota] => 256
    [backlog] => 32
    [stats] => Array
        (
            [today] => Array
                (
                    [sent] => 43
                    [hard_bounces] => 556
                    [soft_bounces] => 64
                    [rejects] => 36
                    [complaints] => 123
                    [unsubs] =>45
                    [opens] => 36
                    [unique_opens] => 45
                    [clicks] =>69
                    [unique_clicks] => 123
                )

            [last_7_days] => Array
                (
                    [sent] => 25
                    [hard_bounces] =>125
                    [soft_bounces] => 29
                    [rejects] => 42
                    [complaints] => 42
                    [unsubs] => 42
                    [opens] => 42
                    [unique_opens] => 42
                    [clicks] => 42
                    [unique_clicks] => 42
                )

            [last_30_days] => Array
                (
                    [sent] => 42
                    [hard_bounces] => 42
                    [soft_bounces] => 42
                    [rejects] => 42
                    [complaints] => 42
                    [unsubs] => 42
                    [opens] => 42
                    [unique_opens] => 42
                    [clicks] => 42
                    [unique_clicks] => 42
                )

            [last_60_days] => Array
                (
                    [sent] => 42
                    [hard_bounces] => 42
                    [soft_bounces] => 42
                    [rejects] => 42
                    [complaints] => 42
                    [unsubs] => 42
                    [opens] => 42
                    [unique_opens] => 42
                    [clicks] => 42
                    [unique_clicks] => 42
                )

            [last_90_days] => Array
                (
                    [sent] => 42
                    [hard_bounces] => 42
                    [soft_bounces] => 42
                    [rejects] => 42
                    [complaints] => 42
                    [unsubs] => 42
                    [opens] => 42
                    [unique_opens] => 42
                    [clicks] => 42
                    [unique_clicks] => 42
                )

            [all_time] => Array
                (
                    [sent] => 42
                    [hard_bounces] => 42
                    [soft_bounces] => 42
                    [rejects] => 42
                    [complaints] => 42
                    [unsubs] => 42
                    [opens] => 42
                    [unique_opens] => 42
                    [clicks] => 42
                    [unique_clicks] => 42
                )

        )

)
```

How can I extract every value as a single line?

Example :

- `$today-sent="43"`
- `$7days-sent="25"`
- `$today-hard_bounces="64"`

Comment: Don't do it.  Arrays are built for this. Just do this: `echo $array['stats']['today']['sent'];` etc...  Why complicate it?

Comment: P.S. `$7days-sent` isn't a valid variable name in PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$todaySent = $array['stats']['today']['sent'];
$lastSeven = $array['stats']['last_7_days']['sent'];
$todayBounce = $array['stats']['today']['hard_bounces'];
```

You can do whatever you want with the variables storing the values.