# extract values from multi dimensional array in php (mandrill)

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, mandrill

another little question: (previous [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27027716/extract-values-from-array-php-or-jquery/27042544#27042544))

if i have an array that needs a loop?

like this one:

```
 /*
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [email] => example email
            [reason] => hard-bounce
            [detail] => 550 mailbox does not exist
            [created_at] => 2013-01-01 15:30:27
            [last_event_at] => 2013-01-01 15:30:27
            [expires_at] => 2013-01-01 15:30:49
            [expired] => 
            [sender] => Array
                (
                    [address] => sender.example@mandrillapp.com
                    [created_at] => 2013-01-01 15:30:27
                    [sent] => 42
                    [hard_bounces] => 45
                    [soft_bounces] => 47
                    [rejects] => 42
                    [complaints] => 42
                    [unsubs] => 42
                    [opens] => 42
                    [clicks] => 42
                    [unique_opens] => 42
                    [unique_clicks] => 42
                )

            [subaccount] => example subaccount
        )

)
```

how can i get on more lines?

like:

1. email@example.com, 45
2. email2@example.com, 45

i love u all guys, u helps me a lot!

Comment: What is your question? How i loop trough a array?

Comment: edited question: have an output like a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo '<table>';
foreach($array as $key => $subArray) {
   echo '<tr><th>' . $key . '</th><td>' . $subArray['email'] . '</td><td>' . $subArray['sender']['hard_bounces'] . '</td><td>' . $subArray['reason'] . '</td><td>' . $subArray['detail'] . '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Ofcourse it does :p Try reading up on using `foreach()` at http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: and if i want to table that? ex keys as rows and 'reason' and 'detail' as column. :)

Comment: a little hint, to format a date from that array? i've tried-> . date_format($subArray['created_at'], 'd/m/y') .

Comment: @MicheleMarri `$time = new DateTime($subArray['created_at']); echo $time->format('d/m/Y');`

Answer (score -4):

[`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function comes to the rescue:

```
implode(', ',               // will prepare a string from array
  array_map(function($el) { // will map existing array to new values
    $result = array();      // prepare result
    foreach(array('email', 'reason') as $name) { // select only email and reason fields 
      $result[$name] = $el[$name];               // setup result
    }
    return $result;         // return to map
  }, $array)
);
```

Comment: help me more please ;) i'm studying this code...

$nameofarray  - is my array
$resultofmapping - is the result to echo

where do i have to put these?

Comment: This is just bad code. Running an iteration within array_map is totally unnecessary. Not just in this case, but in any case.